# Cannot start debezium MySQL connector due to Error code 1236

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When I check the status of my debezium connector via the kakfa-connect's REST API, I see this error message for the connector:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: The slave is
> connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the
> master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave
> requires. Error code: 1236; SQLSTATE: HY000.\n\tat
> io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)\n\tat
> io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:197)\n\tat
> io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader$ReaderThreadLifecycleListener.onCommunicationFailure(BinlogReader.java:997)\n\tat
> com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:950)\n\tat
> com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:580)\n\tat
> com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:825)\n\tat
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by:
> com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.network.ServerException: The slave is
> connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the
> master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave
> requires.\n\tat
> com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:914)\n\t...
> 3 more\n

Is this an issue with how I am configuring my debezium connector or an issue with MySQL? Whats crazy is that even when I tried setting the option `snapshot.mode` to `never` and this error is still being thrown! According to the documentation, when `snapshot.mode` is set to either `never` or `when_needed` it should not require the GTID so I am super confused as to what is happening

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Debezium was probably down for some time and some of the transactions it has not seen are no longer available on the server.

Comment: I have deleted the internal topics for kafka-connect and rebuilt the debezium connector, so how come I am still seeing the message?

Comment: @lollerskates have you solved the issue? What was the root cause? I'm facing the same. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That could be an issue with the wrong offsets for the connector.
So I've deleted the connector, deleted all related Kafka topics (like schema history, etc), and cleaned the offsets using the following guide https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_remove_committed_offsets_for_a_connector
And it helped! After re-creation - the connector works as expected now.